# python list of dictionaries only updating 1 attribute and skipping others

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a list of lists containing company objects:

```
companies_list = [companies1, companies2]
```

I have the following function:

```
def get_fund_amount_by_year(companies_list):
    companies_length = len(companies_list)
    for idx, companies in enumerate(companies_list):
        companies1 = companies.values_list('id', flat=True)
        funding_rounds = FundingRound.objects.filter(company_id__in=companies1).order_by('announced_on')

        amount_per_year_list = []
        for fr in funding_rounds:
            fr_year = fr.announced_on.year
            fr_amount = fr.raised_amount_usd
            if not any(d['year'] == fr_year for d in amount_per_year_list):
                year_amount = {}
                year_amount['year'] = fr_year
                for companies_idx in range(companies_length):
                    year_amount['amount'+str(companies_idx)] = 0
                    if  companies_idx == idx:
                        year_amount['amount'+str(companies_idx)] = fr_amount
                amount_per_year_list.append(year_amount)
            else:
                for year_amount in amount_per_year_list:
                    if year_amount['year'] == fr_year:
                        year_amount['amount'+str(idx)] += fr_amount

    return amount_per_year_list
```

The problem is the resulting list of dictionaries has only one amount attribute updated.

As you can see "amount0" contains all "0" amounts:

> [{'amount1': 12100000L, 'amount0': 0, 'year': 1999}, {'amount1':
>   8900000L, 'amount0': 0, 'year': 2000}]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You provide a function that processes some type of data and it outputs results you believe are incorrect. You don't provide the data being processed and expect us to figure out why you are getting invalid results?

Answer (score 0):

I put list of dictionaries being built in the loop and so when it iterated it overwrote the last input.  I changed it to look like:

```
def get_fund_amount_by_year(companies_list):
    companies_length = len(companies_list)
    **amount_per_year_list = []**
    for idx, companies in enumerate(companies_list):
        companies1 = companies.values_list('id', flat=True)
        funding_rounds = FundingRound.objects.filter(company_id__in=companies1).order_by('announced_on')
```